# ImageIO.read(url x) slow compared to ImageIO.read(file f)

Tags: performance, file, url, javax.imageio

im making a game that needs to load images inside its loop (for animation and stuffs), so i was using this:

```
 url = getClass().getResource("/pic/image.gif");
 pic = ImageIO.read(new File(url.getPath()));
```

that worked perfectly while running the game on the IDE (netbeans) but when i run it form the .jar file after building the project it doesn't work. Reading the API documentation, i saw that there are several overloaded implementations for the `ImageIO.read()` function, one of them using an `url` as a parameter, i thought that it may help me with my problem, and in fact, it did.

```
 pic = ImageIO.read( getClass().getResource("/pic/image.gif") );
```

The problem is that it seem to take too long to load the image this way, making the game slower (not much, but its noticeable). so the question is: Why is the function using the `url` as a paremeter slower than the one receiving a `file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: You say that your game

> needs to load images inside its loop

I don't understand this, and I don't think I agree with the premise.
I/O should *always* be offloaded to a separate thread, if timing and performance is critical.

---

That said, reading from a URL needs more generic code than reading from a file. It needs to handle downloading from an offsite server, files on the local file system, and even uncompressing resources from a JAR. The last one is what you experience.

I'd recommend rewriting the application to *not* read images inside the paint loop, but if you are lazy, you could also unpack the resources to a temp folder (up front) and read from file as before.

`ImageIO.setUseCache(false)` is also likely to help making things a bit faster, by using in-memory caching instead of disk caching while reading the image. Especially when loading from JAR resources.